# Is there a better approach than using stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, sendgrid

Please consider the following code which I am using to get the data posted by Sendgrid.

```
<cftry>              
 <cfset incomingData = toString(getHttpRequestData().content) />
 <cfset djs = DeserializeJSON(incomingData)/>

<cfset a = "0">
<cfset b = "">
<cfset c = "0">
<cfset d = "0">
<cfset e = "">
<cfset f = "">
<cfset g = "">
<cfset h = "">
<cfset i = "">
<cfset k = "#NOW()#">
<cfset l = "">
<cfset m = "">
<cfset n = "">

<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(djs)#" index="i">

    <cfset a = "0">
    <cfset b = "">
    <cfset c = "0">
    <cfset d = "0">
    <cfset e = "">
    <cfset f = "">
    <cfset g = "">
    <cfset h = "">
    <cfset i = "">
    <cfset k = "#NOW()#">
    <cfset l = "">
    <cfset m = "">
    <cfset n = "">

    <cfif StructKeyExists(djs[i],'p')>
        <cfset a       = djs[i].p />
    </cfif>

    <cfif StructKeyExists(djs[i],'q')>
        <cfset b           = djs[i].q />
    </cfif>
    <cfif StructKeyExists(djs[i],'r')>
        <cfset c       = djs[i].r />
    </cfif>
    <cfif StructKeyExists(djs[i],'s')>
        <cfset d       = djs[i].s />
    </cfif>     
    <cfif StructKeyExists(djs[i],'t')>
        <cfset e       = djs[i].t />
    </cfif>
   <cfif StructKeyExists(djs[i],'u')>
        <cfset f           = djs[i].u />
    </cfif>
    <cfif StructKeyExists(djs[i],'v')>
        <cfset g       = djs[i].v />
    </cfif>

    <cfif StructKeyExists(djs[i],'w')>
        {                                                                         
        <cfset i  = djs[i].w />
        <cfset k  = dateAdd("s", i, createDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))/>
        }
    </cfif>
    <cfif StructKeyExists(djs[i],'x')>
        <cfset l         = djs[i].x />
    </cfif>
    <cfif StructKeyExists(djs[i],'y')>
        <cfset m       = djs[i].y />
    </cfif>
    <cfif StructKeyExists(djs[i],'z')>
        <cfset n       = djs[i].z /> 
    </cfif>

    <cfstoredproc procedure="sp1" datasource="db1">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bigint" value="#a#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(b,199)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#c#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#d#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(e,199)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(f,199)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(g,499)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(h,199)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#k#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(l,199)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#LEFT(m,499)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(n,99)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="XX.XX.X.XX">
    </cfstoredproc>


    <cfstoredproc procedure="sp2" datasource="db2">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bigint" value="#a#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(b,199)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#c#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#d#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(e,199)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(f,199)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(g,499)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(h,199)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#k#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(l,199)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#LEFT(m,499)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#left(n,99)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="XX.XX.X.XX">
    </cfstoredproc>   

</cfloop>

</cfoutput>

</cftry>
```

As clear from the above, my code is dependent on the stored procedure on the MySQL Database. I am thinking of getting rid of stored procedure and find a different way where I can accomplish what I am looking for without any stored procedure.Is there a better way other than using Stored Procedure to store the incoming data into database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Is there a better way other than using Stored Procedure to store the incoming data into database?* No, not really. A better question is why you feel the need to stop using the stored procedures?

You really only have three options when interacting with a database; stored procedures, in-line queries (parameterized), or Object Relational Mapping (ORM). Sure you could replace your stored procedure calls with in-line queries or ORM but I don't think you will really gain anything.

Some of the benefits of using stored procedures rather than in-line queries are:

> - **Reduced server/client network traffic**
>     The commands in a procedure are executed as a single batch of code. This can significantly reduce network traffic between the server and client because only the call to execute the procedure is sent across the network. Without the code encapsulation provided by a procedure, every individual line of code would have to cross the network.
> - **Stronger security**
>     Multiple users and client programs can perform operations on underlying database objects through a procedure, even if the users and programs do not have direct permissions on those underlying objects. The procedure controls what processes and activities are performed and protects the underlying database objects. This eliminates the requirement to grant permissions at the individual object level and simplifies the security layers.
>     
>   The EXECUTE AS clause can be specified in the CREATE PROCEDURE statement to enable impersonating another user, or enable users or applications to perform certain database activities without needing direct permissions on the underlying objects and commands. For example, some actions such as TRUNCATE TABLE, do not have grantable permissions. To execute TRUNCATE TABLE, the user must have ALTER permissions on the specified table. Granting a user ALTER permissions on a table may not be ideal because the user will effectively have permissions well beyond the ability to truncate a table. By incorporating the TRUNCATE TABLE statement in a module and specifying that module execute as a user who has permissions to modify the table, you can extend the permissions to truncate the table to the user that you grant EXECUTE permissions on the module.
>     
>   When calling a procedure over the network, only the call to execute the procedure is visible. Therefore, malicious users cannot see table and database object names, embed Transact-SQL statements of their own, or search for critical data.
>     
>   Using procedure parameters helps guard against SQL injection attacks. Since parameter input is treated as a literal value and not as executable code, it is more difficult for an attacker to insert a command into the Transact-SQL statement(s) inside the procedure and compromise security.
>     
>   Procedures can be encrypted, helping to obfuscate the source code. For more information, see SQL Server Encryption.
> - **Reuse of code**
>     The code for any repetitious database operation is the perfect candidate for encapsulation in procedures. This eliminates needless rewrites of the same code, decreases code inconsistency, and allows the code to be accessed and executed by any user or application possessing the necessary permissions.
> - **Easier maintenance**
>     When client applications call procedures and keep database operations in the data tier, only the procedures must be updated for any changes in the underlying database. The application tier remains separate and does not have to know how about any changes to database layouts, relationships, or processes.
> - **Improved performance**
>     By default, a procedure compiles the first time it is executed and creates an execution plan that is reused for subsequent executions. Since the query processor does not have to create a new plan, it typically takes less time to process the procedure.
>     If there has been significant change to the tables or data referenced by the procedure, the precompiled plan may actually cause the procedure to perform slower. In this case, recompiling the procedure and forcing a new execution plan can improve performance.

Some of this is specific to SQL Server but most applies to any database
[Reference - Stored Procedures (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what that stored proc does.  Does it only insert one row of data?

I suggest that you use the loop to put your data into an array or struct then make ONE database call (either via cfquery or cfstoredproc) to insert the data.